# Accessing memory address using format specifiers

Tags: c, printing, casting, format-specifiers

With a for loop I'm trying to print the memory address of each element in an array.

I've tried the following code

```
printf("%p", &arr[i])
```

but my array is of type const word, and word was defined using typedef (although word was defined as type integer in typedef)

now when trying the print statement, I get the error

```
format '%p' expects argument of type 'void *', but argument 2 has type 'const word *'
```

If %p expects an argument of type void *, I thought casting wasn't necessary?

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong. The `%p` format specifiers needs a pointer of type `void*`. Most of the time it works also without `(void*)`, but technically it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Pointer types can be converted to `void *` without a cast in places such as assignment expressions, or in arguments of function calls where the function specifier declares the type of the parameter. However, the declaration of `printf` does not declare the types of any parameters after the format string parameter. These are the "variadic" parameters and the arguments are only converted according to the "default argument promotion" rules. The "default argument promotion" rules do not change the types of pointer arguments. Compilers often include sanity checks for printf-like functions.